# Compare median time between different groups and years

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, survival, median, kaplan-meier

I want to investigate whether there is a difference in median waiting time between different groups in different year. I'll try to explain as best I can.

My data looks like this:

| Year | Country | Waiting time in weeks | Variable 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005 | 1 | 1 | Male |
| 2005 | 1 | 3 | Female |
| 2006 | 2 | 2 | Female |
| . | . | . | Male |

I have a total of five countries and a few variables that I believe might influence the waiting time. In my table above I only mention Variable 1, but in reality there are more.
How would I go about comparing the median waiting time in weeks between the groups and years? Would calculating a Kaplan Meier estimate for median survival time and CI and then compare them CI be plausible?

I would like to answer a question like: Is the median waiting time for country 1 in year 2005 different from the median waiting time for country 2 in year 2005?

Information about data:

- Timeperiod is 2005-2016.
- Waiting time in weeks are individual measurement. Each row corresponds to one individual. With its total waiting time.
- Waiting time is censored for individuals that is loss to follow up or simply didnt experience the event of interest.
- Waiting time in weeks measures the number of weeks from when an individual get signed up on the waiting list until being taken down. You can be taken down for a number of reasons, but I have data on waiting time until they are taken down for example from experiencing the event, or being withdrawn from the waiting list for an unknown reason.
- There are typically around 60 observations per year, and around 54 events. These are of course split among each country.

Comment: Is the waiting time censored, i.e. are there records that are no longer being followed up but whatever they were waiting for didn't happen?

Comment: Do you have individual waiting times, or only a summary in terms of medians? How many cases are there typically per year/country? How many years? Please edit the question to provide that information and what was requested in another comment. If you just respond in comments, others coming to this site might overlook the extra information. Also, comments are pretty easily deleted on this site.

Comment: Edited the post, hopefully the question is more clear now. Thanks!